# Worddpress cron automatically stopped

Tags: wordpress, cron

I have created two wordpress scheduled cron in my site namely "Test_cron1" and "Test_cron2" with time interval "Every 24 hours" and "Every 25 hours". I have created a two function to execute the update functionality while cron run. This works well. But in sometime the cron schedule stopped to work/run. The next cron schedule time will be display something like "1970-01-01 00:00:00"

Sometimes, I hit manually cron schedule function.

Could this happen due to this?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: In addition to code, possible show us the error log?